# How do i get automatic summation of items in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

Am trying to make my QTableWidget get the summation of items from column 2 to column 9. Apparently, i can get it using the following code

```
self.tableWidget.itemPressed.connect(self.summation)

def summation(self):
   row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
   table = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
   try:
       data = sum([int(item.text()) for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems()])
       table.setText(str(data))
   except ValueError:
       pass
   self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 10, table)
```

I want to get the summation just after an item has been entered into the cell with the sum increasing as items are being filled into the cells from column 2 to column 9 having no need of first selecting the items to set the sum.

Comment: have you added some SelectionStrategy or Behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "SelectionStrategy"? Iv'e only done what i've shown. I want the sum of items from column 2 to column 9  on the current row

Comment: so what are your selectedItems? (self.tableWidget.selectedItems())?

Comment: i want the program to automatically select items as they are being added from column 2 to column 9 as the sum of the values is increasing and shown in column 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem sometime back when i changed the number of columns

```
column = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
col = (column - 1)
row = self.tableWidget3.currentRow()
num = self.tableWidget3.item(row, 1).text()
num2 = self.tableWidget3.item(row, 2).text()
num3 = self.tableWidget3.item(row, 3).text()
num4 = self.tableWidget3.item(row, 4).text()
num5 = self.tableWidget3.item(row, 5).text()
add = int(num) + int(num2) + int(num3) + int(num4) + int(num5)
table = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
table.setText(str(add))
self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class window31(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window31,self).__init__()
        self.table=QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setColumnCount(11)
        self.table.setRowCount(35) #setting initial count
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["col "+str(i) for i in range(5)])
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            self.table.setItem(i,9,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.print_it)
        self.show()
    def print_it(self,no):
        if no.column()==9:
            return
        try:
            col9sum=0
            for column in range(2,9):
                try:
                    col9sum+=int(self.table.item(no.row(),column).text())
                except:
                    pass
                self.table.setItem(no.row(),9,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(col9sum)))

        except Exception as E:
            print(E)


app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window31()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

#time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: hey @And3r50n1 I am extremely sorry.This wont work if one edits the cell.So I updated my answer